# Azure Service Bus and CAP theorem

Tags: azureservicebus, cap-theorem

I can't find any info on Azure Service Bus and the CAP theorem.

Does Azure Service Bus choose Availability or Consistency in the presence of a network partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-availability-and-consistency. Although originally written for Azure Event Hubs, the information is also relevant to Azure Service Bus.

Comment: That links helps. I als found this relevant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-outages-disasters#passive-replication (see 'Message delay or loss')